# useEffect renders the other components even if I pass the empty array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As already specified in the title, useEffect renders the other components even if I pass the empty array.

I'm a girl who is just starting to learn react; i can't figure out why if i pass empty array or 'name' in dependency array the action is still the same, but it shouldn't be.

This is my code:

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {  
    return (
      <>       
        {/* First render */}
        <Greet name="Eric" />   

        {/* Second render, name prop changes */}
        <Greet name="Stan" />   

        {/* Third render, name prop changes */}
        <Greet name="Butters" /> 
      </>
    )
  }
```

**Greet.js**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Greet({ name }) {

    const message = `Hello, ${name}!`;  

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`Greetings to ${name}`); // Side-effect!
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>{message}</div>
    )
}
```

From what I understand, with the empty array it only needs to render the first component

Comment: Your question is not clear ? Are you asking why your useEffect run twice even without items in the array ?

Comment: I ask why why does it render all three components; should do the first one or am I wrong?

Comment: You misunderstood the concept of reusable components. can you only use built in elements like `div`, `h1` etc once in your app ? No right ? same goes for custom components. You can use them many time in your ui description.  [see](https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component#using-a-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand 3 concepts here.

First is [reusable components](https://%20Building%20reusable%20UI%20components%20with%20React%20Hooks%20%20LogRocket%20Blog%20https://blog.logrocket.com%20%E2%80%BA%20building-reusable-ui-compo...). When you write something like this in `App`

```
<Greet name="Eric" />   
<Greet name="Stan" />   
<Greet name="Butters" />
```

It will be similar to this in html

```
<div>Eric</div>
<div>Stan</div>
<div>Butters</div>
```

So, in the App component you call the Greet 3 times. It created 3 instances of Greet component

Secondly is [useEffect](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/#21-dependencies-argument),
When you provide an empty dependency array `[]` as the second argument to `useEffect`, it means that the effect will only run once, after the initial render. It won't run again when the component re-renders.

In your case, you have 3 instances of Greet component inside App component, it  run 1 time in 3 instances, so you see 3 console.log display.

Thirdly is how React re-render when something change. Basically, React need something to notify it that the data has changed, and it need to re-render the component accordingly. One simple way is use [useState](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) for the data.

So the example will be something like

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("Eric");

  return (
    <>
      <Greet name={name} />
      <button onClick={() => setName('Stan')}>Change to Stan</button>
      <button onClick={() => setName('Butters')}>Change to Butters</button>
    </>
  );
}

function Greet({ name }) {
  const message = `Hello, ${name}!`;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`1st name ${name}`); // Side-effect!
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`name changed ${name}`)
  }, [name])

  return (
    <div>{message}</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-noyce-f6ldn6?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: it's not clear to me yet. I need more in-depth help

Comment: I've updated the answer with examples @Sarah